# Why is my Python dataclass not initialising boolean correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, python-dataclasses

I'm currently writing some codes for an option pricer and at the same time I've been trying to experiment with Python dataclasses. Here I've two classes, `Option()` and `Option2()`, with the former written in dataclass syntax and latter in conventional class syntax.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Option:
    is_american: Optional[bool] = field(default=False)
    is_european: Optional[bool] = not is_american

class Option2:
    def __init__(is_american=False):
        self.is_european = not is_american

if __name__ == "__main__":
    eu_option1 = Option()
    print(f"{eu_option1.is_european = }")
    
    eu_option2 = Option2()
    print(f"{eu_option2.is_european = }")
```

The output gives

```
eu_option1.is_european = False
eu_option2.is_european = True
```

However, something very strange happened. Notice how in the `Option2()` case, `is_american` is set to `False` by default, and hence `is_european` must be `True` and it indeed is, so this is expected behaviour.

But in the `dataclass` `Option()` case, `is_american` is also set to `False` by default. However, for whatever reason, the dataclass did not trigger the `is_european: Optional[bool] = not is_american` and hence `is_european` is still `False` when it is supposed to be `True`.

What is going on here? Did I use my dataclass incorrectly?

Comment: @user3613025 What he means is we don't need lines like `S0: int` if we are talking only about `is_european: Optional[bool] = not is_american`. They are extraneous and not part of a minimum. That being said, I'll post an answer in a moment.

Comment: @Alan Ok thank you! Part of the reason why I posted the whole code was also that I'm not sure if I also used dataclass correctly on initialising other attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is likely that the dataclass constructor is struggling with the order of statements. Normally you'd have all the mandatory parameters before any optional ones for example, and it may not realise at construct time that the value is meant to be false.

There is a built-in mechanism to make sure that fields which are dependent on other fields are processed in the correct order. What you need to do is flag your secondary code as `init=False` and move them over to a `__post_init__()` method.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional, List

@dataclass
class Option:
    is_american: Optional[bool] = field(default=False)
    is_european: Optional[bool] = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__():
        self.is_european = not self.is_american
```

Personally I'd get rid of `is_european` altogether and use a `get()` to fetch the value if it's called. There's no need to hold the extra value if it's always going to be directly related to another value. Just calculate it on the fly when it's called.

With many languages, you wouldn't access attributes directly, you'd access them through control functions (get, set, etc) like get_is_american() or get_country(). Python has an excellent way of handling this through decorators. This allows the use of direct access when first setting up a class, then moving to managed access without having the change the code calling the attribute by using the `@property` decorator. Examples:

```
# change the is_american to _is_american to stop direct access

# Get is the default action, therefore does not need to be specified
@property
def is_american(self):
    return self._is_american

@property
def is_european(self):
    return not self._is_american

# Allow value to be set
@property.setter
def is_american(self, america_based: bool):
    self._is_american = america_based

@property.setter
def is_european(self, europe_based: bool):
    self._is_american = not europe_based
```

This could then be called as follows:

```
print(my_object.is_american)
my_object.is_american = false
print(my_object.is_european)
```

Did you see how flexible that approach is? If you have more countries that US or European, or if you think the process might expand, you can change the storage to a string or an enum and define the return values using the accessor. Example:

```
# Imagine country is now a string
@property
def is_american(self):
    if self.country == 'US':
        return true
    else:
        return false

@property
def is_european(self):
    if self.country == 'EU':
        return true
    else:
        return false

@property
def country(self):
    return self._country

@property.setter
def country(self, new_country: str):
    self._country = new_country

@property.setter
def is_american(self, america_check: bool):
    if america_check:
        self._country = "US"
    else:
        self._country = "EU"

@property.setter
def is_european(self, europe_check: bool):
    if europe_check:
        self._country = "EU"
    else:
        self._country = "US"
```

Notice how, if you already have existing code that calls `is_american`, none of the accessing code has to be changed even though country is now stored - and available as - a string.

Comment: I had in mind for it to be an Option base class that can either be a put or a call. It then gets inherited by other classes which are meant to be different option pricing models. Could you please elaborate on your `get()` idea?

Comment: Also if I just want to set `self.StockTrees = []`, am I right to just do `StockTrees: List[float] = field(init=False, default_factory=list)` in my dataclass, or should I declare it within `def  __post_init__():`?

Comment: IIRC the way you have done it originally is the right way.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I learnt so much from you today.

Comment: One quibble: unless I'm missing something (testing on 3.10.6), merely changing `is_american -> _is_american` doesn't stop direct access with the @property addition. Is a getter needed to deny direct access?

Comment: @CharlieG There isn't really any way in Python to deny access, unlike many other languages. It is convention only (double underscore does do name mangling, but possible to extract). Hence is_american is the getter for _is_american. See PEP8.

Comment: @Alan that is my understanding as well, thanks for confirming

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is:

```
is_european: Optional[bool] = not is_american
```

`not is_american` is evaluated at *definition* time. At that point, `is_american` is a `Field`, and all `Field`s are truthy. If you want one field defined in terms of another, you'll want to use [post-initialization processing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing) to dynamically select the value of `is_european` after `is_american` is initialized, or make it an `@property` that computes its value live from the value of `is_american` (assuming it's impossible to be both at once).